# How to create four even and fluid css columns?

Tags: css, css-float

I currently have 3 columns that are fluid but they're not even.
I would like to create Four 25% columns that work full width and are fluid.
looked and tried all possible solutions here but ran into a wall.

Here's my CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    min-width:890px;
```

}

```
.threecol .col1 {
    width:46%;
    left:102%;
}
.threecol .col2 {
    width:21%;
    left:31%;
}
.threecol .col3 {
    width:21%;
    left:85%;
}
```

the bottom is for the 3 columns,

any ideas on making 3 even columns and 4 even columns as well will be awesome! HIGHLY appreciated :)

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle with your problem.

Comment: Look up display: table; and table-cell CSS properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ucasip/2/edit Here you go, perfect three & four columns with clean markup.

```
<section class="four">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
  <div class="col3"> </div>
  <div class="col4"></div>
</section>


<section class="three">
<div class="col5"></div>
<div class="col6"></div>
<div class="col7"></div>
</section>



body {
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
        overflow:hidden; }

       .four> div {
        display:block;
        width:25%;
        height:50%;
        float:left; }

       .three > div {
        display:block;
        width:33.33333%;
        height:50%;
        float:left; }


    .col1 {
    background:#000}

        .col2 {
    background:#222 }

        .col3 {
    background:#444 }
        .col4 {
    background:#666}

      .col5 {background:#334455}
      .col6 {background:#556677}
      .col7 {background:#226655}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class=col1>1</div>
<div class=col2>2</div>
<div class=col3>3</div>

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    min-width:890px;   
}

.col1, .col2, .col3 {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}

.col1 {
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
}

.col2 {
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
}

.col3 {
    background-color:#d5d5d5;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the columns to be equal height minimum 100% there is also this solution:

http://jsbin.com/emujeb/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="wrap2">
  <div class="col">
   col
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   col
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   col
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   col
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
.col {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
}
body { 
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0, #eee),
        color-stop(25%, #eee),
        color-stop(25%, #ccc),
        color-stop(50%, #ccc),
        color-stop(50%, #eee),
        color-stop(75%, #eee),
        color-stop(75%, #ccc),
        color-stop(100%, #ccc)
    );      
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
        left, 
        #eee, 
        #eee 25%,
        #ccc 25%,
        #ccc 50%,
        #eee 50%,
        #eee 75%,
        #ccc 75%,
        #ccc 100%,
        #eee 100%
    );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
        left, 
        #eee, 
        #eee 25%,
        #ccc 25%,
        #ccc 50%,
        #eee 50%,
        #eee 75%,
        #ccc 75%,
        #ccc 100%,
        #eee 100%
    );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
        left, 
        #eee, 
        #eee 25%,
        #ccc 25%,
        #ccc 50%,
        #eee 50%,
        #eee 75%,
        #ccc 75%,
        #ccc 100%,
        #eee 100%
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
        left, 
        #eee, 
        #eee 25%,
        #ccc 25%,
        #ccc 50%,
        #eee 50%,
        #eee 75%,
        #ccc 75%,
        #ccc 100%,
        #eee 100%
    );
}
```

This is done with css gradients, but you can replace them if you dont like them with background images and employ the faux column technique.

You would need to style html,body,wrap1,wrap2 as the 4 columns and use background position % to make it happen. Note, you will need long 1px high images to represent the colors, html will have the image shown 25% bakcground color transparent, body will have it at 50% and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Equal height columns done easy:

```
.container {
    display: table;
}

.container .col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sqDNg/